# CodeBlocks can't save shortcuts setting after exiting

Tags: shortcut-keys, settings, code-blocks

Now I know that alot of this question has been asked, but I tried a lot solution and still stuck. Hopefully I will get a way here.
My CB worked well until tonight. I had a situation that lead to restoring CB setting by deleting `default.conf` in `~/.codeblocks` Since that, I can't change any shortcuts. I don't know if deleting `default.conf` has anythign to do with my problem. Whenever I try to do this, CB shows a message:

```
SpellChecker: Thesaurus files '/usr/share/mythes/th_en_US.idx' not found!
SpellChecker: Loading '/usr/share/mythes/th_en_US_v2.idx' instead...
```

So I search for awhile about this thesaurus files missing but still don't have any solution.
Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing it ?

Comment: @George  I do, and I doesn't help. Everything works fine but this feature. And it's really annoying
Edit: I've just remove everything related to CB and reinstall all over. I will tell you if the problem fixed. Thanks

Comment: Sure hope it helps!

Comment: No help, I think the problem is the Thesaurus, which is something related to language-package (or something like this)

Comment: @George Hi, I've just remove and reinstall CB 16.01 (13.12 previously) and it works like a charm. The SpellChecker error still prompts, I have no idea what is going on but everything seems OK now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and still stuck on finding a solution, I've just remove everything related to CB and reinstall CB 16.01 (13.12 previously) and it works like a charm. The SpellChecker error still prompts, I have no idea what is going on but everything seems OK now.